# Keeps counting all the text values instead of me providing a criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, having-clause

I have very simple query, to count the number of Cause Cancel from the Decision column. It keeps counting all the text values in the column and not just cause cancel.

```
SELECT Marketics.Case, Count(Marketics.Decision) AS CountOfDecision
FROM Marketics
GROUP BY Marketics.Case
HAVING Count(Marketics.Decision="Cause Cancel");
```

Comment: Instead of `Having` couldnt you just do a `WHERE Marketics.Decision = "Cause Cancel"`

Comment: In the future, I recommend providing sample data and desired outputs. Even the answer I posted has to make a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, will do Sean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `WHERE` clause not a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Marketics.Case, Count(Marketics.Decision) AS CountOfDecision
FROM Marketics
WHERE Marketics.Decision = "Cause Cancel";
GROUP BY Marketics.Case
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your having clause doesn't have an actual comparison. It just says having count(). They all have a count... so, it's returning correctly.

Now, if your goal is to produce a result with a case number, a count of decisions where it's all decisions EXCEPT  "Cause Cancel" then you need to use a where clause, not a having clause. The having clause will simply filter any cases that don't have at least one "cause cancel" decision.

Of course, that assumes that the count() with an implicit where clause is allowed, which I've never seen before... but I come from a Microsoft SQL background.

```
SELECT Marketics.Case, Count(Marketics.Decision) AS CountOfDecision
FROM Marketics
GROUP BY Marketics.Case
HAVING Count(Marketics.Decision="Cause Cancel") > 0;
```